# How to get the results from the last x days/months/years in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, datetime

I am trying to get a set of results in MongoDB (version 4.2) using only MongoDB Query Language where a specific date is greater than 30 days before today (that is, I need the data from the last 30 days, **starting at 00:00h** of the day 30 days ago).
I have tried this, but it does not yield any results:

```
{
  date: {
    $gte: {
      $dateFromParts: {
        year: {
          $year: new Date()
        },
        month: {
          $month: new Date()
        },
        day: {
          $add: [
            {$dayOfMonth: new Date()},
            -30
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Obviously, I checked that there were results when I entered the date directly this way (being today the 13th of December of 2022):

```
{date: {$gte: ISODate('2022-11-13')}}
```

Thank you for the help!

UPDATE 1:
Thanks to @wernfried-domscheit, I came to this solution, although it is very slow. If there was a solution that does not involve using $expr...

```
{
  $expr: {
    $gte: [
      "$date",
      {
        $dateFromParts: {
          year: {
            $year: new Date()
          },
          month: {
            $month: new Date()
          },
          day: {
            $add: [
              {
                $dayOfMonth:  Date()
              },
              -30
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.find({
   $expr: {
      $gt: [
         "$date",
         {
            $dateSubtract: {
               startDate: { $dateTrunc: { date: ISODate(), unit: "day" } },
               unit: "day",
               amount: 30
            }
         }
      ]
   }
})
```

For older version of MongoDB, use

```
db.collection.find({
   $expr: {
      $gt: [
         "$date",
         {
            $subtract: [
               {
                  $dateFromParts: {
                     year: { $year: ISODate() },
                     month: { $month: ISODate() },
                     day: { dayOfMonth: ISODate() }
                  }
               },
               1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
})
```

Comment: Sadly, $dateSubtract is only available from v 5.0. But you gave me the idea of using $expr. Although, it is horribly slow...

Comment: Please see my update. Do you have an index on `date`?

Comment: Yes, there is an index on date. I notice the performance difference when using the $expr, comparing to querying for the date directly

Comment: You may use a third party date/time library, e.g. [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/index.html#/?id=luxon) then it would be simple `{date: {$gte: DateTime.now().startOf('day').minus({ days: 30 }).toJSDate() }}`